# weird behavior of chrome's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, validation, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have a login form like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="email">
    <input type="password">
</form>
```

When I reload this page, chrome will autofill the form, then I can get the value of email input. But I can't value of password input, if no user action(e.g. click) appeared, what I got is an empty string.

Comment: how is the page served? `file:///`, `http://`, `https://`

Comment: Seems like a useful security feature to me.

Comment: Well, I have to accept that, it appears....